# iPhone sockets working over WIFI but not 3G

Tags: objective-c, ios, sockets

I have a native iPhone app that connects to a client machine via sockets. The connection works over WIFI but does not work over 3G.

Does anyone have ideas what the issue could be?

Thank you.

UPDATE: The client machine is not on the same network as the iPhone.

Comment: What port are you connecting to on your socket? I guess it's possible the cellular provider is blocking you for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that some cellular networks block certain ports. This is why it worked over WIFI but not 3g. One of the reasons why it is better to use web services.

Answer (score 0):

Is this client machine within the same network as the iPhone? Then you can access it over Wifi, but would need a proxy over 3G. Just a guess.

Comment: The client machine is not on the same network but still works over wifi connection. I did not write the app though, how does a proxy work related to sockets?

Comment: Some cellular providers only allow you to access port 80 (http), port 110, and a handful of other ports (ssl, pop3, imap etc). Perhaps your provider is blocking the port this app uses.